# Extension Field of $\mathbb{Q}$ and its Galois group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

How many elements are in $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}:\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Eight.  Galois is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Comment: You really need to tell us what you already know, and what you’ve tried so far.